# Google sheets practicing & training platform

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

Could anyone assist me in finding a good platform that allows me to practice and get more skills regarding Google Sheets?

I need to improve my Google Sheets skills, especially for functions and equations.

Any assistance you could provide me will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try youtube.com It's quite good nowadays if you know English

Comment: And probably you can ask this question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Stay here on SO and try to answer questions and read the answers of others.

Answer (score 1):

I find the best method is to dive in with a practical application and work from there. Find an easy project such as a budget or something you can organize and evolve it over time starting with simple raw data and begin consolidating with formulas. Not only will you find answers to questions you will often use but you will have a sheet that you actually use by the end of it.

The link below is a good source if you are just unaware of the functions available in Sheets. Although it is clear cut and hefty, start with functions you're aware of and perfect them. Or find functions you didn't know exist and play with them.

https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en